# Spring Can I post params array with multipart/form-data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, request

Spring Can I post params array with multipart/form-data

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public Object postData(@ModelAttribute DataDto request) {
  return request;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class DataDto {
  private String number;
  private List<DetailDto> detail;
  private MultipartFile screenshot;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class DetailDto {
  private String code;
  private String desc;
}
```

Result:

> org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'detail[0][code]' of bean class [com.my.project.dto.DataDto]: Property referenced in indexed property path 'detail[0][code]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Map; returned value was [DetailDto(code=null, desc=null)]

Here is UI

```
<form action="http://localhost:8081/test/multi" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="number" value="number" autofocus>
<input type="file" name="screenshot">
<input name="detail[0][code]" value="code">
<input name="detail[0][desc]" value="desc">
<button>submit</submit>
</form>
```

Comment: YES, you can post both params and multipart form data but i think your request body object is not proper please check in DataDto have arrayList, pass the list object in your request.

Comment: and remove the MultipartFile  class from your DataDto and add in your method

Answer (score -1):

please try the code below :

```
    <form action="http://localhost:8081/test/multi" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="number" value="number" autofocus>
    <input type="file" name="screenshot">
    <input name="code" value="code">
    <input name="desc" value="desc">
    <button>submit</submit>
    </form>

    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public Object postData(@ModelAttribute DetailDto request) {
        return request;
    }
```

I hope this will help other people as well :)

Comment: Its no problem with MultipartFile,

Comment: Okeyy. pass the list object in your dataDto object and check.

Comment: My problem is array list detail[0][code]. Is possible to pass param array list in multipart/form-data?

Comment: I pass Class DetailDto to that method and result: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required ArrayList parameter 'detail' is not present

Comment: are you using @RequestBody annotation?

Comment: in your method use like @RequestBody String data

Comment: and after that convert string json to object using ObjectMapper

Comment: No, I use RequestParam, but if i try RequestPart, it still not present, this is the result: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'detail' is not present

Comment: this is result for RequestBody: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryKBEABiZaCSAX6sP6;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Comment: plz change the input name

Comment: yes, i try change html input and RequestParam arg variable to 'dettail'. still same. org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required ArrayList parameter 'dettail' is not present

Comment: can you check dto class i think you have to change dto

Comment: It is not a solution. It is the same as question ...